# Paient ou Payent

Tags: verbes, orthographe, conjugaison

Y a-t-il une règle à propos de ce verbe ? Parce que sur la plupart des sites de conjugaison, c'est écrit

```
Ils paient/payent
```

Les deux orthographes sont-elles acceptées ou y en a-t-il une qui est plus correcte que l'autre ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux sont acceptés et utilisés fréquemment. Aucun me surprend. Pour ma part je trouve que le premier sonne mieux. C'est une question de goût cependant.

Answer (score 4):

Les deux ortographes sont acceptées. Beaucoup de verbes en *-yer* changent le *y* en *i* dans la conjugaison, mais il existe quelques «règles»:

Les verbes en *-ayer* peuvent se conjuguer de deux différentes manières, en gardant le *y* dans toute la conjuguaison ou bien en remplaçant le *y* par un *i* devant le *e* muet. Cette dernière manière de conjugaison est impérative pour les verbes en *-uyer* et *-oyer*.

> - Je paye
> - Je paie

Il est conseillé de choisir une des deux manière et d'être consistent. Alterner entre les deux ortographe ne fait pas preuve d'un bon style d'écriture.

---

Les verbes en *-oyer* et *-uyer* gardent toujours le *y* **sauf** quand le *y* est suivi d'un *e* muet. Dans la  la conjugaison, le *y* est donc souvent remplacé par un *i* étant donné qu'il est souvent suivi d'un *e* muet:

> - Je tutoie
> - Il emploie

Mais lorsqu'il n'y a pas de *e* muet après le *y*, celui-ci n'est pas remplacé:

> - Nous ennuyons
> - Vous avez appuyé